# Day of week constants with Sunday = 0 in Python

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, weekday

The calendar module has day of week constants beginning with

```
calendar.MONDAY
Out[60]: 0
```

However, sometimes one must interface with a system (perhaps written in JavaScript) that uses the convention Sunday = 0. Does Python provide such constants?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no such constants in the Python standard library. It is trivial to define your own however:

```
SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT = range(7)
```

or, when using Python 3.4 or up, you could use the [`enum` module functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api):

```
from enum import IntEnum

Weekdays = IntEnum('Weekdays', 'sun mon tue wed thu fri sat', start=0)

weekday == Weekdays.wed
```

and then you can then also map a weekday integer to an enumeration value by calling the `enum.Enum` object:

```
weekday_enum = Weekdays(weekday)
```

I used 3-letter abbreviations but you are free to use full names if you find that more readable.

Answer (score 7):

I just use this with `mydate.isoweekday()`, does the job.

```
def weekday_sun_zero(self, isoweekday):
    return 0 if isoweekday == 7 else isoweekday
```

Comment: or `return isoweekday % 7` for brevity

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps:

```
from datetime import datetime
weekdays_dic ={0:'Mon', 1:'Tue',2:'Wed',3:'Thu',4:'Fri',5:'Sat', 6:'SUN'}
print(weekdays_dic[datetime.today().weekday()])
```